# Build pull request from forked origins in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to make Jenkins build the pull request my project receives from forks.

I am using the Github plugin and the Jenkins service in Github and I have checked in my Jenkins:

```
Build fork PRs
```

But when Jenkins tries to build I get:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
```

Regular branches builds correctly, but for some reason my PR not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [issue 347](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/347) with a similar problem, using the [GitHub Pull Request Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin).

It pointed out to [this comment](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/412#issuecomment-219096442):

I was able to fix this by editing /etc/default/jenkins and adding the parameters as per [#408](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/issues/408)

```
# ...
# arguments to pass to java
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters=ghprbActualCommit,ghprbActualCommitAuthor,ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail,ghprbAuthorRepoGitUrl,ghprbCommentBody,ghprbCredentialsId,ghprbGhRepository,ghprbPullAuthorEmail,ghprbPullAuthorLogin,ghprbPullAuthorLoginMention,ghprbPullDescription,ghprbPullId,ghprbPullLink,ghprbPullLongDescription,ghprbPullTitle,ghprbSourceBranch,ghprbTargetBranch,ghprbTriggerAuthor,ghprbTriggerAuthorEmail,ghprbTriggerAuthorLogin,ghprbTriggerAuthorLoginMention,GIT_BRANCH,sha1"  # Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
```

> for more info:

- [Jenkins Security Advisory 2016-05-11](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2016-05-11)
- [Plugins affected by fix for SECURITY-170](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170)

> To allow specific, known safe parameter names to be passed to builds, set the system property hudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters to a comma-separated list of safe parameter names. Example:

```
java -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters=FOO,BAR_BAZ,qux -jar jenkins.war
```